Stackelberg duopoly problem
I have a task to use the Stackelberg model, and I'm trying to find the best response function to the 2nd player; it says it should look like a derivative from a function like $q_2\cdot P(Q)-cq$.
For me $c = 0$, so $q_2\cdot P(Q)$. And my $P(Q)$ function looks like $
30\cdot(1-q_1-q_2)^{\frac{7}{9}}\cdot(q_1+q_2)^{-\frac{7}{9}},$ but my $P(Q)$ function derivative looks like:
$-\frac{70}{3(q_1+q_2)^{\frac{16}{9}}\cdot(1-q_1-q_2)^{\frac{2}{9}}}=0.$
And I have no idea how to get $q_2$ from here; how do we manage nonlinear functions in Stackelberg duopoly? What should we do here to get the best response functions in this case?

It would be helpful if you could describe your task problem in detail.

I need to create a mathematical model of the problem
(As I understood is to find players' payoff functions, best response functions for both players) after I need to solve the problem analytically i.e. find the equilibrium values of the strategies and players' profits
Now im stucked with finding best response of both players
All I have is:
P(Q) formula,
amount of players = 2,
Cost function C for both players = 0,
a variable for P(Q) formula = 30

Why have you set $P'(Q)=0$ instead of $P(Q)+q_2P'(Q)=0$?

Firm 2's profit is
$$\pi_2(q_1,q_2)=q_2P(q_1+q_2)$$
The first-order condition for profit maximization (given $q_1$) is
$$\frac{\partial \pi_2}{\partial q_2}(q_1,q_2)=P(q_1+q_2)+q_2P'(q_1+q_2)=0$$
In your case (as you calculated):
$$P'(q_1+q_2)=-\frac{70}{3(q_1+q_2)^{16/9}(1-q_1-q_2)^{2/9}}$$
and so the first-order condition is
$$30\frac{(1-q_1-q_2)^{7/9}}{(q_1+q_2)^{7/9}}-q_2\frac{70}{3(q_1+q_2)^{16/9}(1-q_1-q_2)^{2/9}}=0$$
Multiplying through by $(q_1+q_2)^{16/9}(1-q_1-q_2)^{2/9}$ gives a quadratic to solve:
$$30(1-q_1-q_2)(q_1+q_2)-70q_2=0.$$
(Probably you should also check that the solution is indeed a maximizer.)
